# "Quickblox" android SDK returns null InputStream in CustomObject.downloadFile

Tags: android, quickblox

I am stuck in a problem that when I call `CustomObject.downloadFile` method to download a file it returns success but in the callback in onSuccess the InputStream has 0 size which means its null. Below is my code snippet:

```
QBCustomObject qbCustomObject = new QBCustomObject(Constants.MODULE_1_QUESTIONS,currentQuesData.getQ_id());
QBCustomObjectsFiles.downloadFile(qbCustomObject, "q_image", new QBEntityCallback<InputStream>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(InputStream inputStream, Bundle bundle) {
         Toast.makeText(mainActObj,"succes",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         Bitmap imageContent = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
     }

     @Override
     public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
         Toast.makeText(mainActObj,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

how did you find out

> InputStream has 0 size

maybe BitmapFactory can't decode your image from InputStream? Did you check this issue on other images?